# How auto release works in dynamic range compressor

Tags: dynamic-range-compression

Could anyone help me to understand how auto release mode works in audio dynamic range compressor?

After I typed "auto release" in seatch box on that forum I get "0 results".

Comment: There's no universally accepted formal definition of a *dynamic range compressor*, hence there's also no such definition for the *auto release* functionality. You should describe the structure of the particular system that you are using...

Comment: Oh, actually I am quite noob in the subject, so I am not sure of the definition, but I'll try to explain:
By Dynamic Range Compressor I mean utility that is used by audio engineers to control audio dynamic range. And in the shortest explanation: such compressor is used to automaticaly turn volume down where audio is too loud, and turn volume up when it is too quiet.
Most of those popular compressors have option to set release time to auto. In some way it see the next peak of sound and fit release time to ensure full release before next peak. And I am asking how it works?